patrol 3.6.1 Stuck at app:connectedDebugAndroidTest Failed
Steps to reproduce

Clone https://github.com/alifaalfarizi/test_patrol
Start Pixel_3a_API_33 (Emulator)
Run patrol test patrol test -t integration_test/example_test.dart --verbose

Actual results

I encountered an issue while initializing the Patrol project. Upon initialization, I received the following error message: app:connectedDebugAndroidTest. Upon further inspection, the details of this error appeared to be empty.
Steps Taken:

Initially, I attempted to initialize the project using the Patrol. following the guidelines outlined in https://patrol.leancode.co/getting-started.

The error app:connectedDebugAndroidTest persisted.

I created a new flutter project template https://github.com/alifaalfarizi/test_patrol but the error output still same.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
     * What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
     See the report at: file:///D:/Project/latihan/test%20patrol/test_patrol/build/app/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html    

     * Try:
     > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
     > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
     > Run with --scan to get full insights.

     * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

     BUILD FAILED in 12s
     : > Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
     : 85 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 80 up-to-date
     ✗ Failed to execute tests of apk with entrypoint test_bundle.dart on emulator-5554 
     (Gradle test execution failed with code 1) (12.9s)
     Exception: Gradle test execution failed with code 1
     #0      AndroidTestBackend.execute.<anonymous closure> 
     (package:patrol_cli/src/android/android_test_backend.dart:140:9)
     #1      DisposeScope.run (package:dispose_scope/src/dispose_scope.dart:46:7)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #2      AndroidTestBackend.execute 
     (package:patrol_cli/src/android/android_test_backend.dart:106:5)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #3      TestCommand._execute (package:patrol_cli/src/commands/test.dart:323:7)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #4      TestCommand.run (package:patrol_cli/src/commands/test.dart:215:23)
     #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #6      PatrolCommandRunner.runCommand 
     (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:347:18)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #7      PatrolCommandRunner.run 
     (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:291:18)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #8      patrolCommandRunner 
     (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:70:20)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #9      main 
     (file:///C:/Users/myUser/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/patrol_cli- 
     2.7.0/bin/main.dart:6:20)
     <asynchronous suspension>

     See the logs above to learn what happened. Also consider running with --verbose. If 
     the logs still aren't useful, then it's a bug - please report it.
     Uninstalling com.example.myapp from sdk gphone64 x86 64
     Uninstalling com.example.myapp.test from sdk gphone64 x86 64



</details>
### Patrol version
 patrol: ^3.6.1
### Patrol Doctor output
<details>
<summary>Patrol Doctor output</summary>

Patrol doctor:
Patrol CLI version: 2.7.0
Flutter command: flutter 
  Flutter 3.19.6 • channel stable
Android:
• Program adb found in C:\Users\XPERTSPEDIA\Downloads\scrcpy-win64-v1.24\adb.exe
• Env var $ANDROID_HOME set to C:\Users\XPERTSPEDIA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Flutter Doctor output

Flutter Doctor output **I am using VS code to run the flutter app**
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4291], locale en-ID)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[!] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

